# Lextm SharpSnmpLib Exception {"error in response"}

Tags: sharp-snmp

I am trying the library and am using the sample code provided. I can use snmpwalk and it works fine :
 `snmpget -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`

**Output :**
`SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Administrator admin@test.com
End of MIB`

I also used  **ManageEngine MIBBrowser** and it works fine, but using the library i get the error **{"error in response"}** and when i check the detail of the error, the **ErrorStatus** is **NoSuchName**.

Here is my code 
`c#
var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V1,
                           new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.101"), 161),
                           new OctetString("public"),
                           new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(ObjectIdentifier.Convert(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4"))) },
                           60000);`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. The issue was with the different version of SNMP, i was using V1 but the agent was using V2. So i changed the code to

`c#
VersionCode.V2`

Comment: The VersionCode.V2 resolved the error but i still dont get the right result. I now get the NoSuchObject as a result not an exception.

Comment: http://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/tutorials/introduction.html Check what exact operation you want to perform and then use the correct API please.

Comment: @LexLi Am not sure what that means, as per the above you can see am doing a GET operation. As i mentioned the initial problem was with the SNMP version. I changed to V2 and no exception was thrown. When i use snmpget command line i get the right result but i dont get the result using the library.

Comment: but you were doing WALK by running snmpwalk. That's not a GET at all.

Comment: @LexLi used the wrong example, edited the question to reflect the same snmpget command. Well it turns out the problem was with agent. Seems to work fine on a Windows and Mac client but not the Linux one.

Answer (score 0):

as you said

> The issue was with the different
>   version of SNMP, i was using V1 but the agent was using V2. So i
>   changed the code to

So the actual `ErrorStatus` should be `ReadOnly` at first of your code but as  [SharpSnmpLib](http://help.sharpsnmp.com/html/T_Lextm_SharpSnmpLib_ErrorCode.htm)  describe about `ReadOnly`

> ReadOnly error is generally not used. The noSuchName error is
>   equivalent to this one.

Also make sure that your agent containing OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4` because it looks not valid . I thing it may be `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4`